# How to deploy Nestjs App (on Azure)?

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs

I am trying to deploy a Nestjs API (with Auth0 authentication). When I run it in VS Code with `npm run start:watch server`, everything's fine. 
Now the question is: what should I do to deploy it on a webserver? Should I only copy the dist folder (after runnin `tsc`)? what about node_modules? Should I leave the port to 3000?
As a side note I am trying to deploy it on Azure but I guess the questions holds for any platform.

Many thanks!

Comment: Check this it's same case, May help
https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/asi53v/deploying_nestjs_api_to_azure/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modify your package.json file, and add a `postinstall` script, this script should be `tsc` or `tsc --sourceMap false` if you would like to avoid sourceMaps from being generated.

That would make azure to run tsc after installing all npm packages, remember to change `start` script also, so its value is 'node dist/index.js'

Comment: This answer is correct, but the nestjs starter now has these commands already in the package.json, under "prestart:prod": "tsc ", "start:prod": "node dist/main.js"